# UML diagram and VS2010 IDE

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, uml

Is there any way by which we can generate UML diagrams automatically for my VS2010 project? Is there any free tool for it?  Manually generating UML diagrams is a very time consuming process.... Can anybody help me with an idea as to how I can easily generate UML diagrams for my .net project.

Comment: I know it supports class diagrams, but not sure about other UML diagrams

Comment: UML is not single diagram. It is set of many types of diagrams so you should at least know which type do you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate offers [several types of UML diagrams](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/11/04/visual-studio-2010-uml-modeling-projects.aspx). I think the reverse engineering of the code into diagrams is not part of Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate RTM but can be downloaded as separate [feature pack 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff655021.aspx) (offers generation of UML class diagram from code).

If you don't have VS 2010 Ultimate you should use some other Case tool (most probably commercial because of quality). Very popular is [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/).

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer...i want to know the uml diagram will generate automatically or do i need to generate manually. class diagram generate automatically we know so please tell me it will be generated the same way automatically. anothere question is if i generate a uml diagram then class can be generate automatically beased on diagram. looking for answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much automation you're looking for, but you can generate sequence diagrams relatively quickly in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate RTM, and you can manually create UML class diagrams from C# code by dragging elements, if you have the feature pack:

- [How to: Explore Code with Sequence Diagrams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806.aspx)
- [How to: Create UML Class Diagrams from Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806.aspx)